# Transferred appdata to a new drive, drive broke, can't use most programs

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, taskbar, start-menu

So I had an SSD, 850 Evo msata if it matters, (on an MSI ge70 running Windows 10) that seems to have burned out in less than a year. I was skeptical at first, but I switched ports and it still didn't work. Occasionally it will for a few minutes, but I'll get to that in a sec.

I have it set as my F: drive, and I'd put my appdata into it (my c: had 250 gigs, this had 1tb). This obviously created its own slew of problems (such as not being able to open any Windows store apps, and then having to create new accounts and copy over defaults to make the start menu operational again), and then before I could fix that, boom, the drive with my appdata went kaput.

The weird part is that it doesn't seem completely dead, as occasionally it'll work for the first five minutes or so. Naturally I try to transfer over all appdata, but I can never finish, as it disappears after a few minutes.

I have a warranty on the drive, but before I ring it in, is it actually dead? Is there anything I can do to keep it alive longer? If I can't keep it alive long enough to transfer over appdata, how do I make programs from the other discs usable again?

So many questions, answering any will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Send it to a data recovery company but that likely will void the warranty but they can in theory transfer the cells to a new identical SSD, but your not looking at a cheap operation either.  (Honestly I am only guessing that's even possible based on how Cell phone memory is replace/repaired )

Comment: Thanks. My data is definitely not worth that much, I just have a few programs that I'll need to reauthorize. I think my most important question now is--- how do I make my computer usable again? I can use a few programs, but I can't use chrome or my start menu or taskbar. I'm guessing import tiledatalayer folder from a new account for the start menu stuff, but what about chrome?